# SQL ORDER BY with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to create a view based on an existing table.
The table will be like:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | a1   | a2   | a3   |
| 2    | b1   | b2   | b3   |
| 3    | c1   | c2   | c3   |
| 4    | d1   | d2   | d3   |
| 5    | e1   | e2   | e3   |
| 6    | f1   | f2   | f3   |
+------+------+------+------+
```

The resultant view should have rows in the following manner:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | a1   | a3   |
| 2    | a2   | a3   |
| 3    | b1   | b3   |
| 4    | b2   | b3   |
| 5    | c1   | c3   |
| 6    | c2   | c3   |
+------+------+------+
```

My SQL query looks like this:

```
(select col1 as "col 1",col2 as "col 2",col4 as "col 3" from t1)
union
(select col1 as "col 1",col3 as "col 2",col4 as "col 3" from t1)
order by "col 2","col 3"
```

But the `order by` doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the same order of rows for whatever alias I give after the `order by`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the result table you posted is really what you want?  There is no row in the source where col1=2 and a2 and a3 occur side by side.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the backticks in MySQL and thanks to Andrity M for pointing that. Also there was an ambiguous alias and renaming it fixed the problem. Thank you everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that your MySQL instance is configured to [treat double-quoted strings as string literals rather than quoted identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes). If you use MySQL's native backticks to delimite the names in ORDER BY, [you will get the expected result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53646/2):

```
(select col1 as "col 1",col2 as "col 2",col4 as "col 3" from t1)
union
(select col1 as "col 1",col3 as "col 2",col4 as "col 3" from t1)
order by `col 2`,`col 3`
```

Comment: This gives me an error: "Error Code: 1052. Column 'col 2' in order clause is ambiguous"

Comment: You made it ambiguous then. You can see that my demo doesn't suffer from that problem. Probably you used a name for an alias that was already a name of another column (in your *real* query). That is a completely different issue from what you asked initially, anyway.

Comment: Thank you!! There <i>is</i> an ambiguous alias. My actual query has like 40 columns and I looked into each alias, then renamed the ambiguous one and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from (
  (select col1 as col1,col2 as col2,col4 as col3 from t1)
  union
  (select col1 as col1,col3 as col2,col4 as col3 from t1)
) as t
order by t.col2,t.col3
```

In your case only the second query will order the result.

Comment: Tried that and it gives an error "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: The earlier answer (before this edit) worked too, if I add the back ticks instead of double quotes (t.`col2`)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AId AS A1, BId AS S2, CId  AS S3 FROM(
    SELECT AId, BId, CId FROM TableName
    UNION
    SELECT AId, BId, CId FROM TableName
) AS T ORDER BY S2, S3 DESC
```

But why would you need a union in two identical recordsets?

Comment: Tried it and it gives an error: "Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'col 2'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(select col1 as c1,col2 as c2,col4 as c3 from t)
union
(select col1 as c1,col3 as c2,col4 as c3 from t)
order by c2,c3
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e95382/3)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 
FROM ((SELECT COL1 AS COL_1, COL2 AS COL_2, COL4 AS COL_3 FROM T1) 
UNION (SELECT COL1 AS COL_1, COL3 AS COL_2 , COL4 AS COL_3 FROM T1)) 
ORDER BY COL_1, COL_2
```

Or simply like this:

```
(SELECT COL1 AS COL_1, COL2 AS COL_2, COL4 AS COL_3 FROM T1) 
UNION 
(SELECT COL1 AS COL_1, COL3 AS COL_2 , COL4 AS COL_3 FROM T1)
ORDER BY COL_1, COL_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order by is specifying two constant character strings, rather than column names that contain a space.  Try

```
select col1, col2, col4 as col3 from t1
union
select col1, col3 as col2, col4 as col3 from t1
order by col2, col3
```

This still isn't going to resequence col1 for you.

Comment: Spaces are required for my aliases. I cant change it.